# edge detection with graceless image in python

Tags: python, image, opencv, canny-operator

I have some gray-scale images with very low contrast ([micro-structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yWjN.jpg)) this image shows the delamination of material during degradation, and I want to know the percentage of delamiantion area to the whole picture (like this:[ideal result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVDoo.jpg) ).

I tried to enlarge the contrast with gamma, log, and adaptive adjustment, and I can got the figures like this: [after increase contrast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIXCK.png)

Then I tried to find the threshold and changed the image to black and white image ([black and white image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDGE5.png))

But when I still cannot detect the contour for the delaminated segments, and I got the result like this: [contour detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31tgg.png) (with cv.Canny).

so I am wondering is there good suggestions to find the edge for these delamiantion region?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You got a pretty good black and white image, why not use black and white pixel count instead of getting a contour for area?

Comment: @RockyLi Oh, because the white part inside the circle actually represents the material that is still on the surface, and the white parts outside the circle are the remaining (other materials) after the delamination.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested. But I believe you might want to do the following things:

- Remove the linear gradient of the image in x-direction. The RHS of the image is apparently darker than the LHS. Thresholding will work better if you fix this.
- After thresholding the image, separate disconnected regions in the binary image, then remove regions with small area size
- Do dilation + erosion a little bit to connect the broken ellipses.
- Fill holes in these areas.

The final regions should correspond to the degraded area. You can then extract edges or do whatever you want later.

I was technically a MVTec Halcon user, therefore I'm not exactly sure what are these concepts called in `opencv`, but I believe they should be fairly common operations.

Comment: Thanx! will try!